# Using insertMany creating new collection instead insert to existing collection?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Need to add array of objects to existing collection. Using this code:

```
                    catModel.insertMany(jsonRow,  function(err, videos) {
```

Inside catModel has a property modelName: "Yoga-videos-source"
In mongo has collection "yoga-videos-source".

**Problem:**  After insertMany array of objects adding not to "yoga-videos-source" but creating new collection with name "yoga-videos-sources" (with prefix -s at the end).

**Question** How I can fix this? Why it's happened?

Comment: What does jsonRow look like? Does it have an id field specified?

Comment: Yes, _id specified, and I can't remove _id, because should be same id from original source

Comment: @PärtJohanson can you help?

Comment: Not at this time, busy with other stuff. But for others to consider answering it, you shoud really provide more details, what jsonRow is like, what the existing data is like. You don't have to copy your whole database, but just a few records to make building a minimal working example that one can look at and debug. There are too many unknowns at this point.

Comment: Should be error if I had collisions, but no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem that collections has name such as: "Yoga-videos-source". 
Mongo has specific name convention fro collections, so name should be: 
"yoga-videos-sources"

1) No upper cases
2) End should be "-s"